# Python, run test, send email if it fails

Tags: python

I want to run a test and if it fails, send an email.
Please suggest can I do this with any conventional frameworks like UnitTest. I haven't found a way to modify its behavior when it fails.

Comment: You can write a script that sends an email depending on whether the tests fail or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide your own unittest.TestResult implementation to send email like this:

```
import smtplib
import unittest


def sendmail(from_who, to, msg):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(from_who, [to], msg)
    s.quit()


class MyTestResult(unittest.TestResult):
    def addError(self, test, err):
        self.super(MyTestResult, self).addError(test, err)  
        err_desc = self._exc_info_to_string(err, test)
        sendmail(from_who, to, err_desc)

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        self.super(MyTestResult, self).addFailure(test, err)
        err_desc = self._exc_info_to_string(err, test)
        sendmail(from_who, to, err_desc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule()    
    results = MyTestResult()
    suite.run(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `run()` method of `unittest.TestSuite`/`TestCase` to notify test result via email or any other channels. Check these out:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite.run
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult

Answer (score 1):

You could use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) to handle the test result and emailing. The nice thing about this approach is that you *keep your unit tests unchanged*. That is, you can still run `python mytest.py` without sending off unnecessary emails, e.g. in your local dev environment.

Say you have this unittest in file `mytest.py`:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_spam(self):
         ...
         self.assertTrue(condition) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In your `fabfile.py` add:

```
 def test(from_email="server@mydomain.com",
                 to_email="test@mydomain.com"):
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        result=local('python mytest.py', capture=True)
        if result.failed:
            # prepare message
            msg = MIMEText(result)
            msg['From'] = from_email
            msg['To'] = to_email
            msg['Subject'] = "Tests failed"
            # send email
            s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
            s.sendmail(from_email, [to_email], msg.as_string())
```

Then you can simply call your test as follows:

```
# send to default email address
fab test
# send to another email address
fab test:to_email="other@mydomain.com"
```

Comment: please do comment on -1 so I can improve the answer

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, not all of @GabiMe's answer worked for me. Instead I used:

```
def sendmail(from_who, to, msg):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail(from_who, [to], msg)
    s.quit()

class TestResults(unittest.TestResult):

    def addError(self, test, err):
        super(TestResults, self).addError(test, err)  
        error = self._exc_info_to_string(err, test)
        sendmail(from_who, to, err_desc)

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        super(TestResults, self).addFailure(test, err)
        error = self._exc_info_to_string(err, test)
        sendmail(from_who, to, err_desc)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    suite = unittest.TestSuite(
        unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    )
    results = TestResults()
    suite.run(results)
```

where `tests` is the name of the folder which contain my tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText('todi si tho lift karade :P')

me = 'from_mail@gmail.com'

to = 'to_mail@gmail.com'

pswd = 'abcderfyqwerpokl'

#(if 2 factor-auth is active for your mail, visit https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords select your app device and generate your  12 letter app password, Give those credentials to signin when you are writing the code)

msg['Subject'] = "lift_karade"

msg['From'] = me

msg['To'] = to

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

s.starttls()

s.login(me,pswd)

s.sendmail(me, [to], msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score -2):

you could do a try, except block

```
import script

try:
   script()
except Exception, e:
   import smtplib
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText
   msg['Subject'] = 'Script failed!!'
   msg['From'] = me
   msg['To'] = you
   s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   s.sendmail(me, [you], e.message)
   s.quit()
```